# Visual Studio 2015 low screen Resolution

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have developed a C# Software with Visual Studio. On the Designer pages in the application the images, text and everything else is very clear and with a high resolution. But if I start the app, then the resolution becomes very low. Text and Images are very blurred :(
Can someone help? I'm using the Visual Studio 2015 on my MACbook through Parallels.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related to programming or not..

Comment: What type of application?  WPF or WinForms?

Comment: Please post a screenshot. Is this Windows Forms, WPF, ASP.NET or something else? It sounds like you're running WinForms in a non-high-DPI-aware mode, assuming you have a Retina MacBook and you've configured Parallels to support high-DPI windows applications.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228185/winforms-high-dpi-blurry-fonts

Comment: @BrendanGreen it is a WinForm Application

Comment: @ZetaRift Well I think it is, cause Design is a important part of a high quality software :)

Comment: @Dai it is a WinForm App. And yes I have a retina display. But the forms in the design mode are clear but if I start the application everything is blurred a bit :( I'll put a Screenshot.

Comment: Did you check the linked answer I commented on?  It specifically is about high dpi displays and winforms applications.

Comment: @BrendanGreen i just did, but it doesnt help yet...I'm still trying with this code: 

`[STAThread]
    static void Main() {
        if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6) SetProcessDPIAware();
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());             // Edit as needed
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetProcessDPIAware();`

Comment: @BrendanGreen it doesnt work for me...

Comment: @BrendanGreen The Code? you want to see the code?